# I'm currently looking for a dynamic way to convert rows to columns in a specific way in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm currently looking for a dynamic way to convert rows to columns in a specific way in SQL server (I was able to do it in excel vba but the excel limitations made me go to SQL).

Abstract : I am making a daily analysis over 10 years considering 1315 stocks, for each stock we have daily returns for a period going from 29/12/2009 to 30/12/2016.

As you can see every 2614 row there's a new stock with the 3 following rows showing text..

Table on SQL

[image]

And I would like to obtain this result.. therefore looking for a good insight to help me go through this!

Desired solution draft

[image]

I am doing this for a quantitative department in Luxembourg to implement a dynamic model allocation of smart betas. (First time with SQL)

Thank you for your help! feel free to ask any questions if you need any other detail..

R.H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also known as a *dynamic pivot* -- for sql server see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455/1327961